# Implicit Type Promotion Order for Custom Class

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am writing a class for which I want to allow conversion to and from various other classes, including built-in types.  I have an implicit conversion priority order in mind, but I don't know how to express it.  This results in ambiguous method overloads when the types mismatch.  For example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int x) : m(x) {}
    operator int() const { return m; }
    Foo operator+(const Foo& foo) const { return Foo(m + foo.m); }
private:
    int m;
};
```

Given the above class definition, the expression `Foo(3) + 7` results in a complation error, *Foo::operator+: 2 overloads have similar conversions*.  I know this is because the compiler doesn't know whether I want to cast `Foo` down to `int`, or construct a temporary `Foo` from `int`.  How would I specify that I always want to prefer constructing a temporary `Foo`?

And more generally, if I also want to define both `Foo::Foo(Bar)` and `Bar::Bar(Foo)`, how would I specify that if I call `Foo(3) + Bar(7)` that I would always want a temporary `Bar` constructed from `Foo`?

Updating to clarify my requirements:

1. Both conversion directions must exist.  So the following must still compile:

   `int i = 3; Foo foo(i); float a[4]; a[foo];`
2. I do not want to have to explicitly specify the preferred cast (e.g. by calling`Foo(3) + static_cast<Foo>(7)`).
3. I do not want to define overloads for every permutation of operator and operand type (e.g.`Foo::operator+(int)`).  I want to rely on implicit conversion to `Foo` followed by `Foo::operator___(Foo)`.

Comment: Remove the conversion function?

Comment: @KerrekSB I still want to allow implicit down-conversion for functions and operators that do not accept `Foo`. For example, I want `myFloatArray[Foo(3)]` to still compile.

Comment: OK. Please edit your question to make *all* your requirements explicit. The next option would be to add your own operator overloads for things like `operator+`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Updated requirements - I'd prefer to avoid your "next option" if possible.

Comment: Do not allow any implicit conversions. They are a huge pain and cause innumerable hard-to-find bugs. One of the biggest mistakes of C++.

Comment: @n.m. Explicitly defining each overload seems like it would be more error-prone, not to mention bloating the number of methods of each class by an order of magnitude.  Also the implementation would just be equivalent to what I'm hoping to accomplish with implicit overloads, i.e. `X::operatorQ(Y y) {this->operatorQ(X(y));}` for cases where `X` is a "higher type" than `Y`.

Comment: I'm far from defending large sets of overloads either, they are bad in their own way. I'm pretty much happy with explicit conversions. If you must have implicit promotions I could understand that somehow, but implicit two-way conversions are pure insanity.

Comment: Can you tell us more specifically about this thing that can be used exactly like an int but isn't an int? Maybe your real use case will indicate a solution.

Comment: @MarkB I'm creating a math library for use in time-limited programming competitions, so I want my classes to behave like `int`s when I want an `int`, with an absolute minimum of both typing time and cognitive friction, even if that means dramatically higher cost in the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ language has no way to specify an implicit conversion precedence order and I can't see any way to meet all your requirements.

The best solution here is to remove your `operator int()`. I know you said you don't want that alternative , but calling `.get()` is only six more characters of typing, *once* when you first write it. Then not only does it solve your ambiguity but it can prevent obscure bugs due to implicit conversion to int. Those are the kinds of bugs where you stare at the code for two days (pretend you're maintaining your code two years later) and still can't see the bug because you don't realize the implicit conversion has been used.

Comment: Is that just your recommendation or is there truly no way to accomplish what I want in C++?